# Stabilizers of points in the upper half-plane

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a group acting discontinuously on $\mathcal{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Im}(z) > 1\}$. In order to keep things simple, suppose that $\Gamma \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and is acting via the linear fractional transformations. In general, for $z \in \mathcal{H}$, what can be said about $\operatorname{Stab}_{\Gamma}(z)$? Of course, it is very well-known that $\operatorname{Stab}_{\operatorname{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})}(i) = \operatorname{SO}(2)$. I have also seen that when $\Gamma$ is a quaternion algebra over a totally real number field $F$, certain points' stabilizers are CM extensions of $F$ (contained in $\Gamma$). Are there any other exceptional examples? Specifically, when $\Gamma$ is a quaternion algebra?